# Error connecting to SQL from WCF Using LINQ - but affects only one server

Tags: sql, linq, wcf, linq-to-sql

That's a horrible title, sorry.

Here's the scenario:

WCF Service uses LINQ to get data from a SQL database.  Service is deployed on 4 (nearly) identical servers running under IIS.  All are talking to the same SQL server on a separate machine.

3 of the 4 servers are working great.

On the 4th server we're getting this

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

The exception is thrown the first time that my LINQ DataContext is used to execute a query.

All 4 servers are using the same connection string, defined in their machine.config.

On the problematic server, I am able to connect using SQL Management Studio with the same credentials that are in my machine.config.  I have also written a simple command line client that does an ADO.NET connection to the database server using the same connection string.  It works.

The same identical code is deployed to all 4 servers, with identical configs.

**What could possibly be causing only my client on just the one server to throw this error?**

I've done everything I can to rule out the usual suspects (port blocked by firewall, remote access not enabled on SQL Server, using a named SQL instance, etc).  I've also checked to see if there any hardcoded connection strings in my code, or elsewhere in the config hierarchy.  As best as I can tell that's not the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got this working.  I don't totally understand the problem, but the gist of it was that the db server didn't have TCP/IP enabled, just named pipes.  The 3 servers that were working were able to connect via named pipes.  The bad server was not able to use named pipes - I *think* because it was on a different network (or segment) than the db server.

What I still don't understand was why I was able to use SQL Mgmt Studio to connect from the bad server.  If neither TCP/IP nor pipes was available, how was it connecting?  Is there some other connection method?

So I'm glad it's working, but a little uncomfortable that I don't completely understand the underlying problem that caused it.